# Media Playlist Plugin

Tags: plugins, php, javascript, audio

Alright so recently I purchased an audio player called "Liner" and I am working with it now converting it into a WordPress plugin but the one thing I am having the most problems with is the fact that the tracks need to be manually added..

Here's a snippet of my JS.

```
<script>
    jQuery(function($) {
        $('body').linerPlayer({
            firstPlaying: 0,
            autoplay: true,
            shuffle: false,
            //veryThin: true,
            slideAlbumsName: true,
            nowplaying2title: true,
            roundedCorners: true,
            //accentColor:"#cc181e",    //008DDE            
            pluginPath: "/canyon/liner/", // <<< IMPORTANT! - Change this to your path to the plugin folder
            playlist: [ //♩ ♪ ☊ ♫ ♬ //
                {mp3:"song/songname.mp3", title:"song title", artist:"song artist", album:"name", cover:"song/cover.png"},
            ]
        });

    });
</script>
```

I am wondering if there is anyway that I could write to this JS to fill out the song MP3 and then making the title as example

```
<?php the_title(); ?>
```

And the artist as the

```
<?php the_tags(); ?>
```

But with out me manually having to add anything to the player? How would I start on doing this.. just some ideas will help me a lot because I am really stuck right now.

Comment: search around for `wp_enqueue_script` for adding your js file, and `wp_localize_script` for passing data from php to your script.

Comment: @milo I have taken a look at both of the functions you have provided and I still don't see how it would prevent me from manually having to add the audio.. I assume I would need to make a short code which would write another line into the JS file but I don't think that's it at all..

Comment: you're not writing anything to a js file, your js file would be updated to reference the data object that you create after you enqueue the script. you populate the data object with whatever data you want to pass from php to javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a quick example showing how you would pass php data to your script.

First, we hook our function to the `wp_enqueue_scripts` action. Inside, we enqueue the script that contains the player and initialization code (this is probably two separate files, but I've condensed it to a single file in this example). Next, we call `wp_localize_script` and set some data we want available in our script.

```
function wpd_test_localize_script() {
    if( is_single() ){
        global $post;
        wp_enqueue_script(
            'test_script',
            get_template_directory_uri() . '/script.js', // or plugins_url() if this is plugin, not theme
            array( 'jquery' ),
            null,
            true
        );
        wp_localize_script(
            'test_script',
            'test_script_data',
            array(
                'title' => $post->post_title,
                'file' => 'hello.mp3'
            )
        );
    }
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpd_test_localize_script' );
```

Next, we look at the `script.js` file we enqueued above, and we can see here how to access the data we passed to it via `wp_localize_script`:

```
(function($){
    $(window).load(function(){
        alert( test_script_data.title );
    });
})(jQuery);
```

`test_script_data` is the object we created with `wp_localize_script`. If we load a single post page, the above code will pop an alert dialog with the current post's title.

If we look in our page source, we can see the script tag WordPress created which contains our data:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
/* <![CDATA[ */
var test_script_data = {"title":"Some post title","file":"hello.mp3"};
/* ]]> */
</script>
```

We can pass an array of data as we do above, or we can nest any number of arrays to create multi-dimensional data if necessary (like multiple tracks, each with title, file, etc.).